# Training loss value is increasing after some training time, but the model detects objects pretty good

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, loss-function

I encounter a strange problem while training CNN to detect objects from my own dataset. I am using transfer learning and at the beginning of training, the loss value is decreasing (as expected). But after some time, it gets higher and higher, and I have no idea why it happens.

At the same time, when I look at *Images* tab on Tensorboard to check how well the CNN predicts objects, I can see that it does it very well, it doesn't look as it is getting worse over time. Also, the Precision and Recall charts look good, only the Loss charts (especially classification_loss) show an increasing trend over time.

Here are some specific details:

- I have 10 different classes of logos (such as DHL, BMW, FedEx, etc.)
- Around 600 images per class
- I use tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu 18.04
- I tried multiple pre-trained models, the latest being *faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco* with this config pipeline:

  ```
  model {
    faster_rcnn {
      num_classes: 10
      image_resizer {
        keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
          min_dimension: 600
          max_dimension: 1024
        }
      }
      feature_extractor {
        type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101'
        first_stage_features_stride: 16
      }
      first_stage_anchor_generator {
        grid_anchor_generator {
          scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
          aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
          height_stride: 16
          width_stride: 16
        }
      }
      first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
        op: CONV
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.0
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.01
          }
        }
      }
      first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
      first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
      first_stage_max_proposals: 300
      first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
      first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
      initial_crop_size: 14
      maxpool_kernel_size: 2
      maxpool_stride: 2
      second_stage_box_predictor {
        mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
          use_dropout: false
          dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
          fc_hyperparams {
            op: FC
            regularizer {
              l2_regularizer {
                weight: 0.0
              }
            }
            initializer {
              variance_scaling_initializer {
                factor: 1.0
                uniform: true
                mode: FAN_AVG
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      second_stage_post_processing {
        batch_non_max_suppression {
          score_threshold: 0.0
          iou_threshold: 0.6
          max_detections_per_class: 100
          max_total_detections: 300
        }
        score_converter: SOFTMAX
      }
      second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
      second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    }
  }

  train_config: {
    batch_size: 1
    optimizer {
      momentum_optimizer: {
        learning_rate: {
          manual_step_learning_rate {
            initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
            schedule {
              step: 900000
              learning_rate: .00003
            }
            schedule {
              step: 1200000
              learning_rate: .000003
            }
          }
        }
        momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      }
      use_moving_average: false
    }
    gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
    fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/franciszek/Pobrane/models-master/research/object_detection/logo_detection/models2/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco/model.ckpt"
    from_detection_checkpoint: true
    data_augmentation_options {
      random_horizontal_flip {
      }
    }
  }

  train_input_reader: {
    tf_record_input_reader {
      input_path: "/home/franciszek/Pobrane/models-master/research/object_detection/logo_detection/data2/train.record"
    }
    label_map_path: "/home/franciszek/Pobrane/models-master/research/object_detection/logo_detection/data2/label_map.pbtxt"
  }

  eval_config: {
    num_examples: 8000
    # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
    # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
    max_evals: 10
  }

  eval_input_reader: {
    tf_record_input_reader {
      input_path: "/home/franciszek/Pobrane/models-master/research/object_detection/logo_detection/data2/test.record"
    }
    label_map_path: "/home/franciszek/Pobrane/models-master/research/object_detection/logo_detection/data2/label_map.pbtxt"
    shuffle: false
    num_readers: 1
  }
  ```

Here you can see results that I get after training for nearly 23 hours and reaching over 120k steps:

- [Loss and Total Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJnMI.png)
- [Precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REZcW.png)

So, my question is, why is the loss value increasing over time? It should be getting smaller or stay more or less constant, but you can clearly see the increasing trend in the above charts.
I think everything is properly configured and my dataset is pretty decent (also .tfrecord files were correctly "built").

To check if it is my fault I tried to use somebody's else dataset and configuration files. So I used the [racoon dataset](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) author's files (he provided all of the necessary files on [his repo](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon-dataset)). I just downloaded them and started training with no modifications to check if I would get similar results as him.

Surprisingly, after 82k steps, I got entirely different charts than the ones shown in the linked article (that were captured after 22k steps). Here you can see the comparison of our results:

- [My losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJBVX.png) vs [his TotalLoss](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*mbK-cbCZxJBEs1IXdt0Ipw.png)
- [My precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV2Nk.png) vs [his mAP](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*SIaM74Rv9K5FFsGRq8qOOw.png)

Clearly, something worked differently on my PC. I suspect it may be the same reason why I get increasing loss on my own dataset, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `totalLoss` is the weighted sum of those four other losses. (RPN cla and reg losses, BoxCla cla and reg losses) and they are all **Evaluation loss**. On tensorboard you can check or uncheck to see the evaluation results for training only or for evaluation only. (For example, the following pic has train summary and evaluation summary)

[image]

If the evaluation loss is increasing, this might suggest an overfitting model, besides, the precision metrics dropped a little bit.

To try a better fine-tuning result, you may try adjusting the weights of the four losses, for example, you may increase the weight for `BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss` to let the model focused on this metric better. In your config file, the loss weight for `second_stage_classification_loss_weight` and `first_stage_objectness_loss_weight` are both 1 while the other two are both 2, so the model currently focused on the other two a little more.

An extra question about why `loss_1` and `loss_2` are the same. This can be explained by looking at the tensorflow graph.

[image]

Here `loss_2` is the summary for `total_loss`, (note this total_loss is not the same as in totalLoss) and the red-circled node is a tf.identity node. This node will output the same tensor as the input, so `loss_1` is the same as `loss_2`

Comment: Thanks for reply! But have a look at my tensorboard screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/bhSNZT1.png
As you can see, I have both orange and blue ticks checked (I guess "." is my train folder and "eval_0" evaluation folder - it was automatically created after starting training, I don't know how to change it - maybe you will help me with that too?), but in the Loss tab there are only blue datapoints (evaluation scores?) and no orange ones. At the bottom of the page there are also "loss_1" and "loss_2" charts with only orange datapoints, so I guess that would be the training loss?

Comment: Here you can see the "loss_1" and "loss_2" charts: https://i.imgur.com/2n3u5Tu.png
So, if it is the training loss, then it is in fact decreasing as it should. So maybe you are right that evaluation loss increasing suggests overfitting of the model. But why are there two training losses looking exactly the same?

Comment: They are the same if you look at the tensorflow graph, two summaries `loss_1` and `loss_2` are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. :) But there is still one more mystery to be solved - look at the end of my original post. Do you have any idea why my results differ so much from the results provided by the author of linked article? I used exactly the same dataset files, config files, model files etc as he did and I got something completely different.

Comment: I would not say it is completely different but yours seem to have more oscillations. Obviously you trained your model for much more steps so the plots are more squeezed. When training, there exist some random options like in data augmentation there is random flips, also the optimizer is momentum which may behave differently when the order of training inputs is different. So there are a lot reasons to not be able to reproduce the same plot. (But it should be resonable to reproduce on your own machine using same configs, etc.)

Comment: I can only say that probably you can adjust your learning rate to a smaller value to make the loss plot more flat.